# Which puran describes about the curse of kashyap rishi by which Shiva had to behead his son?

Tags: scripture, puranas, identification-request, curse

I have not found any description in shiv puran, that Shiva was cursed by kashyap rishi, by which he had to behead his own son Ganesha? Then which puran describes about it?

Answer (score 5):

You can find that in [Brahmavaivarta Purana: Ganapati Khanada: Chapter 18](https://archive.org/details/357106450BrahmavaivartaPurana2SanskritTextWithEnglishTranslationPdf/page/n677):

> [Kashayapa] Finding his son falling pronounced a curse on Shiva that the way in which you have killed my son similarly the head of your son will also be shattered.